# How to make text file like a table which contains of column and row in Java

Tags: java, authentication, text-files

Currently, I am trying to make a login system which included username password and account type.

My text file.

username |password |type

admin |admin |administrator

test |test |manager

.
.
After a lot of research, what I can do is either read single column or read single row.
I want to make it like a database which we could retrieve only username or only password at a specific row at the same time.

Please help, I am very new to Java (my lecturer required me to do this in text file, else I will do in database. "I am able to do it in database").

Comment: Thank you man!! i think this is what i am finding =D

Comment: why don't you read row by row and store it in a 2d array.

Comment: I would read the file in, something like `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` would do.  Split each line `Scanner` or `String#split` would do.  I would place the resulting elements into some kind of POJO and place that into a some kind of `Map` keyed to the user name.  This means, you can simply look up the POJO which matches a given user name and get the details from it.

Comment: Have a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) and [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be quite easy to do this. I assume you're acquainted with reading text files, because you haven't asked about that.

What I would do, then, is read the file line-by-line, saving the lines individually to one string variable, let's call it `readString`. Immediately split readString by your delimiter, in this case " |" (don't forget the space!).

```
String readArray=new String[3];
readArray=readString.split(" |");
```

If the first split of the string (`readArray[0]`) does not match the username inputted by the user, then overwrite readString with the text file's next line, split it again, check it against the inputted username, and continue until a match is found. When a match is found, check the second split of the string (`readArray[1]`) against the password. If those also match, sign that user in as the account type found in `readArray[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty hard to do this using a text file. But if you really need to, you could save each entry in a line, separated by a space.

When you need to search for a value in a column, you could read each line in the file, one-by-one, user .split() on it and get the values of individual rows, and then check for a match.

Keep doing this until a match is found.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading google java api... It has a data structure Table which might be helpful.

[Google API](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table)